# Can't Get Membership Username in LogOn Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Here is my LogOn Action:

```
Public Function LogOn(ByVal model As LogOnModel, ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        If Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password) Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)
            If Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) AndAlso returnUrl.Length > 1 AndAlso returnUrl.StartsWith("/") _
               AndAlso Not returnUrl.StartsWith("//") AndAlso Not returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\") Then
                Return Redirect(returnUrl)
            Else

                ' redirect based on whether the user is admin, company owner, or blog owner

                Debug.Print(Membership.GetUser.UserName)
```

When I try to debug the variable, it says, "NullReferenceException, Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

It was just working a minute ago!  How can I get the username variable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the authentication cookie adds it to the response of the current request.  The cookie is not yet present in the request until after the response is sent to the client, and the client sends it in subsequent requests.

The good news is that you already have the username from the model so I would suggest using that.

Comment: That works and was good advice.  However, I am curious as to why it was working before and suddenly stopped...  I was using Membership.GetUser.UserName and it was giving me the username!

Comment: Is it possible that the cookie was already being sent up, but was subsequently cleared or changed?

Comment: I assume that it is possible but I am not sure.  Thanks for your help, Dan.

Comment: So, Dan, is it possible to get the user ID or anything from the transaction?  Or will I need to just take the username and create a new user object filtered by a lamda to get a user entity with that user name?

Comment: That would depend on the membership provider, but if you're just using the default ASPNETDB SQL database, you could always just query the db for the user with the specified name.  Of course, you're already querying the database when you call the ValidateUser method.  It would probably be better to replace that with a call that gets the user and its data out of the database provided the username/password represents a valid user, and return null if the username/password are invalid.  Only set the cookie if a non-null value were returned.

Comment: I was able to do this: 
Dim userKey As Guid = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName, True).ProviderUserKey
Since I can just get the ID that way, I can use that as a foreign key to any other table I need.  I just hope it's secure.  It seems like it can only be called once the user is authenticated.